# R Shiny get IP adress return from asynchronous call javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, asynchronous, shiny

I am trying to get client IP adress using javascript on my R Shiny App. `alert` print the right result, function is working in `javascript` as stand alone but the return is `NULL` in R.

I suspect that the problem is an asynchronous call that does not wait to return immediately because `alert` provides the right result. I tried to modifiy my javascript to get it synchronous but still get the same result.

An other way to get IP adress in R might be accepted.

File `app.R`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- function(req) {
  fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = "
    shinyjs.getIP = function(){
      $.getJSON('https://ipapi.co/json/').then(function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data.ip, null, 2));
        return JSON.stringify(data.ip, null, 2);
      });
    }

    shinyjs.getIP2 = function(){    
      var jqxhr = $.getJSON('https://ipapi.co/json/');
      jqxhr.done(function(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data.ip, null, 2));
        return JSON.stringify(data.ip, null, 2);
      });
    }
    ")
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ip <- reactive(js$getIP())

  observe({
    print(ip())
  })

  ip2 <- reactive(js$getIP2())

  observe({
    print(ip2())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can use the function *Shiny.setInputValue(id,value)* (see [Communicating with Shiny via JavaScript](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html)).
This function enable to set input variable from javasript to R.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script('
  var coords = $.getJSON("https://ipapi.co/json/", function(data) {
   Shiny.setInputValue("ip", data.ip); //set value from data.ip in js to input$ip in R
  });'
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderText({ input$ip })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I need !